# Error running app : 'xxx multiply defined'

Tags: blackberry, multiple-definition-error

What should one do to build blackberry apps for different OS versions? I've seen strange behavior when the same app runs well at 9700 OS 5.0, 9800 6.0 but gives an error at 9700 OS 6.0:

> Error Starting jokes_480x360_: Class 'com.core.controller.LastMessages' multiply defined

Comment: Solved. The problem was that another version of the application was already installed on the device, which caused this error. Remove and reinstall is the solution.

Comment: To follow the pattern of stackoverflow, you ought to put your solution as an answer to your question (yes, you can answer your own question).

Answer (score 0):

A version of your application is already installed.
Remove it before installing.
Refer to this [article](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Application-throws-quot-multiply-defined-quot-error-at-start-up/ta-p/501498) in Blackberry Knowledge base